# how do you prevent someone from double clicking a <tr> ng-click in an angular binded html?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

So basically, I have this line of code;

```
<tr data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-packageinfo" ng-click="retrievePromoData({!! $pPackages['iid']!!}, {!! $pPackages['prices']['0']['price']['floorPrice'] !!})"> 
   <td>                                                                                                                                                          
   {!! $pPackages['name'] !!}                                                                                        
   </td>
   <td class="hidden-xs">{!! $pPackages['sku'] !!}</td>                                                                                    
   <td>{!! $pPackages['prices']['0']['price']['floorPrice'] !!}</td>
</tr>
```

now the problem is, when i click the tr, it works fine, but when i double click, or keep clicking it, it overloads the javascript. how do i prevent someone from clicking the tr more than once? or prevent the event from firing more than once? Note: my ng-click is in a tr, and i've tried $event.stopPropogation(); as well as setting a flag in the javascript, they both don't work. Any help would be deeply appreciated! cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a class as follows:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

In ng-click of < tr> add this class to < tr> using ng-class.

Comment: can you show the code what have you done? 
have you included css, is css being applied?

Answer (score 0):

Check in progress in your controller.

```
$scope.inProgress = false;

retrievePromoData(){
  if(!$scope.inProgress){
    $scope.inProgress = true;
    // your code

    $scope.inProgress = false;
  }
}
```

also try this if necessary

```
<tr ng-class="{'disabled' : inProgress }" >
```

with class

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: hey there @ankur, thanks for the quick response, yeap, i've tried this earlier, by setting a flag, it doesn't seem to work though..

Comment: I have updated answer. try that it should restrict click until current process complete